# Views Row style Node heading between different dates

Tags: 7, views

I need a view that display full nodes. So I have set my row style to Node. SO I have.

- Node 1
- Node 2
- Node 3

What I want is

- 11/05/2010

  1. Node 1
- 10/05/2010

  1. Node 2
  2. Node 3

I want to place a heading between each group of nodes on a certain date. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need fields to group by date. You can use [Views node field](http://drupal.org/project/viewsnodefield) to have a field that shows as a node (with a choice of build mode). I think that should work.